# create html table in outlook with specific style color and border using vba

Tags: css, vba, html-table, outlook

I am trying to create a `table` in `html body` of `outlook`. Table has been created very well with correct headings and data rows, but the style is not what it suppose to. I need to have every other row with different color also the header text and background color need to be changed, I am looking for a comprehensive answer for the possibilities of styles we can manage?

Following is `VBA` code:

```
    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
        
        
    For Each cCel In eSh.Range("A2:A" & eSh.Cells(eSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        ' Clearing values
        cCel.Offset(0, 2) = ""
        
        If IsEmpty(cCel.Offset(0, 1)) Then GoTo NX
        
            mSend = False
            EmailBody = ""
                
            ' Salutation
            ' this is the possible line to be changed in order to get the particular style ???
            EmailBody = "<style> th , td { border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; padding: 4px 8px; text-align: left; } tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color: #e7edf0; }</style>Ola, " & _
            cCel & "<br><br>" & _
            "<table><tr><th>Numero do Contratro</th><th>Contratante</th><th>Saldo de Contrato</th></tr>"
            
            ' Filter
            DB.Range("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=gestI.Column, Criteria1:=cCel
        
        If DB.Range("A" & DB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then GoTo NX

        
        For Each mCel In DB.Range("AG2", DB.Range("AG" & DB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            If mCel.Row = 1 Then GoTo NXX
            If Not IsDate(mCel) Then GoTo NXX
            
            'mCel.Select
            exDate = DateSerial(Year(mCel) + 1, Month(mCel), Day(mCel))
        
            If DateDiff("d", Date, exDate) < 0 Then
                mSend = True
            
                EmailBody = EmailBody & "<tr>" & _
                "<td>" & DB.Cells(mCel.Row, "C").Text & "</td>" & _
                "<td>" & DB.Cells(mCel.Row, "I").Text & "</td>" & _
                "<td>" & DB.Cells(mCel.Row, "X").Text & "</td></tr>"
            
            End If
        
NXX:        Next mCel

        If mSend = False Then GoTo NX

        Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        With EmailItem
        
            .To = cCel.Offset(0, 1).Text 'Email address from DataBase
            
            .Subject = "Información Sobre Contractos"
                        
            .HTMLBody = EmailBody & "</table><br><br>Atenciosamente"
            
            .Display
            
            .Send
            
            cCel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Sent" 'mark the mail
            X = X + 1
        End With

NX:     Next cCel
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `GetInspector.WordEditor` property to paste the formatted table?
Several times ago I've written a function to paste table to e-mail

```
Function SendTable(rng As Range, Email As String, Subja As String)  ', Emltext As String)
    rng.CurrentRegion.Copy
      Dim myInspector As Object
       Dim wdDoc As Object
       Dim myitem As Object
       
       
    Set myitem = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    Set myInspector = myitem.GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor
     
    With myitem
    
         .To = Email
         .Subject = Subja
    '     .Body = Emltext
         .Display
        
    End With
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs.Add
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs.item(1).Range.Text = Emltext& vbCr
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs.Add
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs.Add
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs.item(3).Range.Text = "Hello2" & vbCr
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs.Add
    rng.CurrentRegion.Copy
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteExcelTable False, True, False'here is pastes the table
    wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.Select
    
    
    End Function
```

and in code this function looks like

```
  Sub test()
    Dim OA As Object, oitem As Object
    
    Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Set oitem = OA.CreateItem(0)
    oitem = SendTable(Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(4, 4)), "xxxxxx@xxxx.ru", "Report "&Now)  
    
    End Sub
```